# i cant change active class in a list

Tags: jquery, menu

i 'm troubling with jquery scripts and codes. there are my codes and i cant find why it doesnt works?

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jsproj</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jsproj.css">
    <script src="jsproj.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
    <li>list item 4</li>
    <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

css file :

```
#nav li /* this is the off state */
{
    background: #79ff3a;
}

#nav li.active
{
    background:red;
}
```

and finally it is jquery scripts :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#nav li').on('click', function(){
        //$(this).addClass('active').removeClass('off').siblings().addClass('off').removeClass('active'); // no need to add .off
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    });
})
```

;

my pc specs : 
1- windows 8 64 bit 
2- i already installed node js and brew...

Comment: You have not added jQuery library. Apart from that, Your code works see http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/8au1b4f3/

Comment: works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/c9o6uj4L/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `jQuery` library in header, add this line in your `head` tag.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsproj.js"></script>
</head>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#nav li').on('click', function(){
        //$(this).addClass('active').removeClass('off').siblings().addClass('off').removeClass('active'); // no need to add .off
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    });
})
```

```css
#nav li /* this is the off state */
{
    background: #79ff3a;
}

#nav li.active
{
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
    <li>list item 4</li>
    <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```